Dynamically outputs the coordinates of points on a function
How to invoke Mathematica's built-in dynamic features, as shown in the figure, when I hover the mouse over the function image, Mathematica dynamically displays the coordinates of this point, and I want to dynamically assign the coordinates of this point to a variable

i have write a code to achieve this function, but if the function is more complicate, it will be very slowly.
Manipulate[DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, closestPoint}, EventHandler[Dynamic[Module[{mousePos, curvePos}, 
 mousePos = MousePosition["Graphics"];
 If[mousePos === None, mousePos = pt]; 
 curvePos = {mousePos[[1]], f[mousePos[[1]]]};
 closestPoint = curvePos; 
 Show[Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-10, 10}}], 
  Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[closestPoint]}], 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Style["red point location: " <> ToString[closestPoint], 12, 
    Bold] ]]], {"MouseMoved" :> (pt = 
   MousePosition["Graphics"])}]], {{f, Sin}, {Sin -> "Sin"}}, TrackedSymbols :> {f}]



I think you shouldn't invent your own function, because you can simply leverage what has already been done with the dynamic highlighting mechanism in plots. For example, you can use CoordinatesToolOptions to extract the current values:
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, 
 CoordinatesToolOptions -> {"DisplayFunction" -> 
    Function[pt, coords = pt]}, PlotLabel -> Dynamic[coords]]


